# how to hide warning in bash script

Tags: bash, warnings

I have a bash script I've been using for ages.  It has a few lines it just start/stop some jobs in database. It is very simple and it never fails. Last year, it facts in December so a few days ago :) I migrated whole data to a new machine. And then my problem starts. 
Now script works as it worked before but now it returns warning. Below output:

```
[oracle@SVMSLUATTIADB1 ~]$ ./batch.sh stop 
./batch.sh: line 87: warning: here-document at line 85 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `!')
./batch.sh: line 87: warning: here-document at line 85 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `!')

Batch_Executer_1                                   [NOT OK]

Batch_Executer_2                                   [NOT OK]

[oracle@SVMSLUATTIADB1 ~]$
```

The piece of code mentioned in warning is:

```
batch_stop()
{
  for BATCH in $BATCHES
  do
    SQLRES=`sqlplus -S "/ as sysdba" << !
      exec dbms_scheduler.disable('"AIT"."${BATCH}"', TRUE);
   `     << line 87
  done
}
```

So the question is how to avoid/hide this warnings. It is not critical, script works as it worked but the view of warning disturbs. I see that before I had bash version 3.2.25  but now it is bash 4.1.2.

I tried to modified my code and redirected output :

```
   {SQLRES=`sqlplus -S "/ as sysdba" << !
              exec dbms_scheduler.disable('"AIT"."${BATCH}"', TRUE);
           ` } 2>/dev/null
```

but it didn't help :(

Comment: @user3863616, fix the here document syntax. Try [this](https://gist.github.com/d2ccbe03143c350f5b11fe4dc1914e8e), for example.

Comment: bingo , problem solved    **($**   instead of  **`**    thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is caused by invalid [here document](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) syntax. Namely, the second limit word (`"!"`) is missing.

Also, don't use back quotes for command substitution. Use the `$(...)` syntax instead, as it is more readable, and it can be nested.

The fixed version:

```
SQLRES=$(sqlplus -S "/ as sysdba" << !
exec dbms_scheduler.disable('"AIT"."${BATCH}"', TRUE);
!
)
```

Note, the here document ends on a line containing only the limit word (the exclamation mark, in particular). So it is not allowed to indent the second limit word, for example.

Comment: your last remark is probably the most important :)   no spaces before and after exclamation mark